# Update values from NULL to specific value stored in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a newbie to SQL so need help and suggestion on one thing which i came across.

My table looks like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4 
   1     AA      BB     NULL 
   2     AA      BB     NULL 
   3     AA      BB     1000 
   4     CC      DD     NULL 
   5     CC      DD     2000
```

I want to update the NULL values of `Col4` with respective value at `Col4` where `Col2` and `col3` values are same.

Like in my first row `Col4` is having NULL while in 3rd row `Col4` has value (with same `Col1` and `Col2` value)

I just want to know is there any way that I can update the NULL with specific values.

Comment: What if there are more than 1 row with value? Which one will you choose?

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table t1
join
(
  select col2, col3, max(col4) as col4
  from your_table
  group by col2, col3
) t2 on t1.col2 = t2.col2 and t1.col3 = t2.col3
set t1.col4 = t2.col4
where t1.col4 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a `join`:

```
update table t join
       (select col2, col3, max(col4) as col4
        from table t
        group by col2, col3
       ) tt
       on t.col2 = tt.col2 and t.col3 = tt.col3
    set t.col4 = tt.col4
    where t.col4 is null;
```

Note:  this chooses the maximum value of `col4` assuming that multiple rows have values.